# python logging into a forum

Tags: python, authentication, phpbb3, typeerror

I've written this to try and log onto a forum (phpBB3).

```
import urllib2, re
import urllib, re
logindata = urllib.urlencode({'username': 'x', 'password': 'y'})
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login"[logindata])
output = page.read()
```

However when I run it it comes up with;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/python/test urllib2", line 4, in <module>
    page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login"[logindata])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

any ideas as to how to solve this?

*edit*

adding a comma between the string and the data gives this error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/python/test urllib2", line 4, in <module>
    page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login",[logindata])
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 192, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url, data)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 327, in open_http
    h.send(data)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\httplib.py", line 711, in send
    self.sock.sendall(str)
  File "<string>", line 1, in sendall
TypeError: sendall() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not list
```

*edit2*

I've changed the code from what it was to;

```
import urllib2, re
import urllib, re
logindata = urllib.urlencode({'username': 'x', 'password': 'y'})
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login", logindata)
output = page.read()
```

This doesn't throw any error messages, it just gives 3 blank lines. Is this because I'm trying to read from the log in page which disappears after logging in. If so how do I get it to display the index which is what should appear after hitting log in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login"[logindata])
```

is semantically invalid Python.  Presumably you meant

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login", [logindata])
```

which has a comma separating the arguments.  However, what you ACTUALLY want is simply

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login", logindata)
```

without trying to enclose logindata into a list and using the more up-to-date version of urlopen is the urllib2 library.

Comment: Invalid is a little vague.  It's syntactically valid.  It just has a type error because the index is a urlencoded dictionary, not an integer.

Comment: That's a good point; I've edited my response to say "semantically invalid", since as you point out it's valid syntactically.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL string shouldn't be

```
"http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login"[logindata]
```

But

```
 "http://www.woarl.com/board/ucp.php?mode=login", logindata
```

I think, because [] is for array and it require an integer. I might be wrong cause I haven't done a lot of Python.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a comma between the string,`"http:..."` and the urlencoded data, `[logindata]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a type on logindata, you can see that it is a string:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> logindata = urllib.urlencode({'username': 'x', 'password': 'y'})
>>> type(logindata)
<type 'str'>
```

Putting it in brackets ([]) puts it in a list context, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score -1):

This would be easier with the high-level "mechanize" module.